# How is scoring determined when a block is broken in DX-Ball 2?

Tags: dx-ball-2-20th-anniversary-edition

Whenever I break a block In [*DX-Ball 2: 20th Anniversary Edition*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/922400/DXBall_2_20th_Anniversary_Edition/), the amount of points I get always seems to vary. Some of the variance can be attributed to the type of block destroyed and the double points powerup, but the score seemingly varies even when breaking two blocks of the same type.

What determines how many points you get when a block is destroyed in DX-Ball 2?

[image: Animated gif showing variations in scores earned when breaking blocks]
<sub>Broken blocks earning 20, 22, and 21 points respectively ([Source](https://store.steampowered.com/app/922400/DXBall_2_20th_Anniversary_Edition/))</sub>